How to test parameters/args in gtest/gmock within expect_call
i started unit-test with gtest and gmock. I want to test the content of an EXPECT_CALL in one line. How to do it the right way?
My example code:
class MockClientSignalEventHandler
    : public ISignalFunctionFeatureEventHandler<Data, Id>
{
public:
    MockClientSignalEventHandler() = default;
    MOCK_METHOD(void,
                onSignalEvent,
                (const std::shared_ptr<Id> &id,
                 const std::shared_ptr<Data> &data),
                (override));
};

Now i want to check it in EXPECT_CALL. How can i check shared_ptr in EXPECT_CALL?
The code now looks like this:
EXPECT_CALL(*mockEventHandler, onSignal(::testing::_, ::testing::_)).WillOnce(ReturnFromDetached(&cv));
    feature->handleFeatureMessage(messageHeader, data);
    std::mutex mx;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mx);
    cv.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::seconds(5));

Instead of ::testing::_ i want to check the content of shared_ptr.
Thanky you for your help!
